Loop over the CSV and generate dataframe
We are looping over the CSV file process the CSV and store the result into string variable .
string is in below format
Loop iteration 1 -- string1--> CS,20,20021988,Ind 
Loop iteration 2 -- string2--> FQ,20,,Aus 
loop Iteration 3 -- string3 -->SR,,,US


If you see number of fields within string are not consistent , Is there any way to store this results into pyspark dataframe during each loop . I e. append each record into dataframe during each iteration
looking final dataframe Result like below


What do you mean the number of fields is inconsistent? Every loop I see 4 fields, although sometimes they are NULL/Blank. AT any rate if you have a csv and you want to read it into a dataframe you can do that directly with spark.read.csv() no reason to introduce expensive loops into the process.

Inconsistent fields meaning  , Sometimes i get data like below first row has 3 fields and second has 2

FIRST ROW -->FQ,20,Aus
SECOND ROW--.>SR,12
THIRED ROW-->PQ

does the file retain the commas? do you mean SR,12,,? if so, the fields are consistent.

It's still not clear to me what the problems is FQ,20,,Aus, SR,,,US, and PQ,,, are all consistently 4 fields in a comma delimited file. If that's what ends up in your strings, then it's still consistent as string1.split(',') on all three would yield a list with 4 entries.
